# Process size continuously increasing by a program in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a program that lists the files in the directory & compress files in the directory. But the process of this program takes memory which gets continuously increasing. Here is the program:

```
' Get list of directories
For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(scandir)
    Dim zipPath As String = fromPath.Text + Dir.Replace(scandir, "") + Dir.Replace(scandir, "") + ".zip"

    'Open the zip file if it exists, else create a new one 
    Dim zip As Package = ZipPackage.Open(zipPath, _
        IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)

    showfiles.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Dir : " + Dir + Environment.NewLine)
    Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Dir)

    Dim fileComparer As IComparer = New CompareFileByDate()
    Array.Sort(files, fileComparer)
    Array.Reverse(files)

    For Each f As String In files
        Dim fia As FileInfo = New FileInfo(f.ToString)

        Dim cta As DateTime = fia.LastWriteTime
        If cta >= fromdt And cta < todt Then

            'Add as many files as you like:
            AddToArchive(zip, f)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(f)

        End If

    Next
    zip.Close() 'Close the zip file
Next
```

In the above code, what objects are not getting destroyed which is taking memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see with regard to memory usage, is that you are not disposing of the `ZipPackage`. You should wrap it in a `Using` ... `End Using` block:

```
Using zip As Package = ZipPackage.Open(zipPath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)

    ' ....

End Using
```

One other thing you can do, is move this line:

```
Dim fileComparer As IComparer = New CompareFileByDate()
```

Outside of the loops.

**Unrelated to the memory usage:**

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(f)
```

If saving the ZIP file fails, you will have lost (deleted) all of the original files, without being able to recover them.

Comment: Probably AddToArchive method is not disposing resources aswell